# WampServer HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, wampserver

Hello I want to learn more about WampServer an HTTPS. 
I have this [website](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,32986).

But if i give the command:

> openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024

it will give me an error called:

> he ordinal 3807 could not be located in the dynamic link libary
>   LIBEAY32.dll

I have Look on my directory:

> wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin

there was a file called libeay.dll.
What coud be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The openssl executable that is distributed with Apache for Windows and therefore WAMPServer does not seem to work very well. I have never had the time to work out exactly why!

My solution was to download OpenSSL from [Shining Light Products](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) They are linked to from the [Openssl Binaries page](https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) so I assume it is a stable and unhacked distribution of a windows binary etc that does the job for windows users.